# Extract columns containing a particular word

Tags: r

My file is like this-

```
ball    cat     bird    ball    cat     cat     ball
apple   mouse   apple   apple   mouse   mouse   apple
cat     bat     mouse   cat      bat    bat     cat
mouse   ball    bat     ball    ball    ball    ball
bat     ball    mouse   bat     bat      bat    bat
bird    ball    ball    bird    bird    bird    bird
```

I want to extract those columns which contain word "apple"

Expected output-

```
ball    bird    ball    ball
apple   apple   apple   apple
cat     mouse   cat     cat
mouse   bat     ball    ball
bat     mouse   bat     bat
bird    ball    bird    bird
```

Comment: Is your file a raw text file? Do you want the output to be a raw text file? How are  you importing the data in R?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So many ways to do this , also I think this must be answered somewhere

1) Using `colSums`

```
df[colSums(df == "apple") > 0]

#     V1    V3    V4    V7
#1  ball  bird  ball  ball
#2 apple apple apple apple
#3   cat mouse   cat   cat
#4 mouse   bat  ball  ball
#5   bat mouse   bat   bat
#6  bird  ball  bird  bird
```

2) with `apply`

```
df[apply(df == "apple", 2, any)]
```

3) Using `Filter`

```
Filter(function(x) any(x == "apple"), df)
```

4) `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% select_if(~any(. == "apple"))
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(V1 = structure(c(2L, 1L, 5L, 6L, 3L, 4L), .Label = 
c("apple", 
"ball", "bat", "bird", "cat", "mouse"), class = "factor"), V2 = 
structure(c(3L, 
4L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("ball", "bat", "cat", "mouse"
), class = "factor"), V3 = structure(c(4L, 1L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 2L
), .Label = c("apple", "ball", "bat", "bird", "mouse"), class = "factor"), 
V4 = structure(c(2L, 1L, 5L, 2L, 3L, 4L), .Label = c("apple", 
"ball", "bat", "bird", "cat"), class = "factor"), V5 = structure(c(4L, 
5L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L), .Label = c("ball", "bat", "bird", "cat", 
"mouse"), class = "factor"), V6 = structure(c(4L, 5L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 3L), .Label = c("ball", "bat", "bird", "cat", "mouse"
), class = "factor"), V7 = structure(c(2L, 1L, 5L, 2L, 3L, 
4L), .Label = c("apple", "ball", "bat", "bird", "cat"), class = "factor")), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `sapply` from `base R`

```
df[sapply(df, function(x)  'apple' %in% x)]
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(V1 = structure(c(2L, 1L, 5L, 6L, 3L, 4L), .Label = c("apple", 
"ball", "bat", "bird", "cat", "mouse"), class = "factor"), V2 = structure(c(3L, 
4L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("ball", "bat", "cat", "mouse"
), class = "factor"), V3 = structure(c(4L, 1L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 2L
), .Label = c("apple", "ball", "bat", "bird", "mouse"), class = "factor"), 
    V4 = structure(c(2L, 1L, 5L, 2L, 3L, 4L), .Label = c("apple", 
    "ball", "bat", "bird", "cat"), class = "factor"), V5 = structure(c(4L, 
    5L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L), .Label = c("ball", "bat", "bird", "cat", 
    "mouse"), class = "factor"), V6 = structure(c(4L, 5L, 2L, 
    1L, 2L, 3L), .Label = c("ball", "bat", "bird", "cat", "mouse"
    ), class = "factor"), V7 = structure(c(2L, 1L, 5L, 2L, 3L, 
    4L), .Label = c("apple", "ball", "bat", "bird", "cat"), 
    class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

Answer (score 0):

If the columns might contain a large number of different values and processing time or performance becomes an issue, you can first cast the columns as factors and look for matches in the levels, as opposed to iterating over the entire dataset.